# Unable to use RTSP with MediaCapture UWP

Tags: uwp, rtsp, mediacapture

Following this article:
https://blogs.windows.com/windowsdeveloper/2019/10/10/connecting-network-cameras-to-windows-10-devices/
We can initiate MediaCapture with RTSP URI link in constructor.
I'm using VLC and IpCameraEmulator as RTSP streamers. I've also tested stream with VLC player.
This code should open stream, but I get native exception which I cannot resolve.

```
var mcis = new MediaCaptureInitializationSettings()
    {
        DeviceUri = new Uri("rtsp://127.0.0.1:8554/live"),
        StreamingCaptureMode = Windows.Media.Capture.StreamingCaptureMode.Video
    };

await mediaCapture.InitializeAsync(mcis);
```

Exception throws at InitializeAsync(bool) with following message: "The specified object or value does not exist. (Exception from HRESULT: 0xC00D36D5)" and because it came from native(?) source, I can't find reason why it happens.
My UWP app preparations are correct as I know: target and dev machine with Windows 11 build 22000 and minimum required is Windows 10 build 20348. Visual Studio 2022. Additionally, disabled firewall.

Comment: What is the value of `mediaCapture` and `mcis` when you call the `InitializeAsync` method?

Comment: Hi, thank you for reply. What do you mean? mediaCapture created without any custom configuration with mediaCapture = new MediaCapture(); . mcis inited with DeviceUri and capture mode.

Comment: I was asking about debugging information. I'm interested to know what these variables are when the program executes the line where the exception is being thrown.

Comment: The problem seems to be more related to the device. Does the built in camera app work with the camera?

Comment: @JunjieZhu-MSFT yep, camera is working. Other external USB cameras also work fine. I don't think the root cause came from device, because I'm trying to use network protocol for images stream. Also, for a clear test I'm creating tcp/udp RTSP stream with vlc locally on laptop.